# How to filter duplicate records from observable collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, group-by, observablecollection

Currently i am filtering my duplicate records from observable collection using Group-By with single field.
Que 1:

my Current Code to filter records

```
if (param.ToString() == "Name")
        duplicates = AllCollection != null
                         ? AllCollection .GroupBy(g => g.Name).Where(w => w.Count() > 1).OrderBy(o => o.Key).Select(s => s).ToList() :
                         Collection.GroupBy(g => g.Name).Where(w => w.Count() > 1).OrderBy(o => o.Key).Select(s => s).ToList();
else if (param.ToString() == "Company")
      duplicates = AllCollection != null
                          ? AllCollection .GroupBy(g => g.CompanyName).Where(w => w.Count() > 1).OrderBy(o => o.Key).Select(s => s).ToList() :
                          Collection.GroupBy(g => g.CompanyName).Where(w => w.Count() > 1).OrderBy(o => o.Key).Select(s => s).ToList();
```

But using this i need to use else if for all fields for filtering.
Any other method to do it without using this big code..

Que 2:

Also i want to filter records with multiple fields
E.g
With passing Name and ComapnyName and result would be Records with same Name and Company name.
So which Linq expression i can pass into Group-By Clause?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? if all you want to do is remove duplicate entries then .Distinct() should be enough.

Comment: @Vinay Pandey No, I don't want to remove duplicate entries, I want to display duplicate entries values

Comment: so what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I am not facing any problem when passing one field to filter,i can groupby with one column easily now i want to groupBy with more then one column e.g Name and CompanyName i want to groupBy with both but can't create GroupBy expresion Dynamically.As I know how to groupBy with more column but using that syntax i need to pass static field

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue with just checking value is null or not in grouping clause,if value value is null in collection then grouping is null and move to check for next field and if value is not null then group-by with field.

```
duplicates = AllCollection != null
                             ? AllCollection.GroupBy(g => new {Name =IsNameChecked && Name!=null ?g.Name:null}).Where(w => w.Count() > 1).OrderBy(o => o.Key).Select(s => s).ToList() :
                             Collection..GroupBy(g => new {IsNameChecked && Name!=null ?g.Name:null}).Where(w => w.Count() > 1).OrderBy(o => o.Key).Select(s => s).ToList();
```